# Use Enum value set in the bean from Java Script

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, enums

I want to check the `enum` value set in the managed bean from a `java script` in `JSF`. How can I do this?

My JSF has something like below.

```
<script language="javascript">

      function displayMsg() {
          setwindowOverlayPos('popup_window',  - 100,  - 150);
      }

      window.onload = function () {

     // this is the enum value I want to check. if the value is cust1 ,  I call the popup window.

          var cust1= '#{myBean.customerType.custType == "cust1"}';  

          if(cust1){
            displayMsg();
          }

      }
 </script>
```

I have enum for customer types

```
public enum CustomerTypeEnum {


CUST1("CUST1"),
CUST2("CUST2");

private String custType;

private CustomerTypeEnum(String s) {
    custType = s;
}

/**
 * @return customer type
 */
public String CustomerTypeEnum() {
    return custType;
}
```

}

And my Managed bean having

```
@ManagedBean(name = "home")
@ViewScoped
public class HomeBean extends BaseOrderStepBean {

     private CustomerTypeEnum customerType;

     public void method1(){

         customerType = CustomerTypeEnum.CUST1;
     }


}
```

Comment: Your post not clear enough !

Answer (score 0):

I write this for benifit of others. I got this fixed. Only have to change the javascript a bit like below.

```
          var od = '#{MyBean.customerType.custType == "OD"}';
          var alreadyHasIC = '#{sessionBean.icNumber}'
          if ("true" == od) {
              if(!alreadyHasIC){
                  displayMyForm();
              }
          }
```

Which means can access the Bean's Enum from the Java script like this.